react-bootstrap: No animations on dropdown close
I want to add animations to Dropdown component. So I thought that I could wrap Dropdown.Menu component with Collapse transition:
<Collapse in={show}>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Collapse>

And it works for when opening dropdown (animation is present). But when I close it - no animations.
There is full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ryls9z?file=src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev

OK, IMHO I found solution (not sure if it's the best/right way - I'm new to React and React Bootstrap).
Animations works but it isn't visible because Dropdown.Menu is instantly hidden (class show removed) when Dropdown.Toggle is triggered (pressed). My first idea was to manually control it with show property of Dropdown.Menu, but it's overridden by Dropdown context...
Then I noticed that I can add such CSS rule to achieve that I need:
.collapsing.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

